# Xamarin.Forms : how to install NGraphic package in UWP Project

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, ngraphics

I have a Xamarin cross-platform project which contains an Android and an iOS app. Now I want add new UWP project, but there certain packages which are not compatible with UWP but are compitible with Android and IOS.
Packages like: NControl.dll, NGraphics.dll

Comment: Looks `NControl` and `NGraphics` are not supported in UWP at the moment. You may want to reach out the developers on the project github

Answer (score 0):

At the time of my writing this answer, UWP is not supported for those packages; but there are open Pull Requests to add UWP support to both NControl & NGraphics:

- NControl: https://github.com/chrfalch/NControl/pull/71
- NGraphics: https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics/pull/63

As such, you can likely track these pull requests to get an idea of if & when that support is added. I cannot speculate on a timeframe or any certainty of whether or not these pull requests will be approved eventually; for example it is possible support could be added from other pull requests instead.